# Using Where clause in Case to compare

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, case, ssms

I am new to T-sql .

I am using the following Query:

```
SELECT e.Id,e.cAvg,
CASE 
    WHEN e.cAvg<=0.8 and cAvg>=0 THEN t.Model when t.Cr='0.8' then t.Model 
    WHEN e.cAvg>0.8 and cAvg<=5.4 THEN t.Model WHEN t.Cr='5.4' then t.Model 
    WHEN e.cAvg>5.4 and cg<=8 THEN t.Model WHEN t.Cr='8' then t.Model 
    ELSE 'No Change Required'
  END
  from A e, B t;
```

What I am trying to do is:

- Select id and cAvg columns in Table A.
- Compare cAvg in Table A with Cr in Table B.
- Use the comparison in CASE to select the particular row which satisfies the condition.
- Use the selected row to give query results.

t.Model is a column of table B. I want to select t.Model value of the selected row in the case statement.

I feel the way is to somehow include a equivalent of the where clause inside When of CASE.

Need Direction!!

The table schema:

Table A:

```
+----+------+
| id | cAvg |
+----+------+
|  1 | .8   |
|  2 | 5.4  |
|  3 | 6.0  |
+----+------+
```

Table B:

```
+-----+-------+
| Cr  | Model |
+-----+-------+
| 2   | M1    |
| 5.5 | M2    |
| 8   | M3    |
+-----+-------+
```

I want to the following:

- Compare the values of cAvg with a condition => (cAvg<=8 And cAvg>=5.5 => the model selected must be M3.)

The result I want to get is:

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | cAvg | Model |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | .8   | M1    |
|  2 | 5.4  | M2    |
|  3 | 6.0  | M3    |
+----+------+-------+
```

I tired Join as suggested in the comments, A great thanks , I learnt a lot because of it!!.

My problem is that there are no common columns to join.
Also I need to compare the column in one table with that of another table and then give a result based on the comparison.

I referred to many answers in stack overflow but all the answers are for the premise where there is a common column.

I tried the following:

- Inner Join
- Cases

I need a direction as to which direction I need to go into.
Thank you!!

Comment: You need to join your tables, you're getting a cartesian product by not issuing join conditions. Switch to explicit `JOIN..ON` syntax (it's the standard for as long as i can remember)

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins to learn how to use `FROM A JOIN B ON ...`

Comment: Also show some sample data (enough to meet all of your conditions) and desired results. Word problems and a query that doesn't do what you want aren't enough to write a query that does.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: @HoneyBadger Hi,Thanks for the direction into Joins, I tried it but my problem is there are no common columns between the table. I realize the description was vague therefore I have updated the question. thank you for the help!!

Comment: @AaronBertrand Hi, Thank you for the heads up, thank you!! I realize the description was vague therefore I have updated the question.

Comment: @PeterB Hi , Thank you for the reference, went through it. The main problem I am facing is that there are no common columns between the table. I tried union and cross join, but i don't want any columns of table B to be selected in the query, I want the table B for just comparing and determining which Model value to select. No clue how to achieve it, help much appreciated:)

Comment: In your code, you are doing `when t.Cr='6'` but there **is no such value**. Same for values `12` and `24` - or are you not showing us the full content of that table?

Comment: @PeterB Oops!! sorry, I just created a schema equivalent to the table and put in some dummy data, I will edit the code to match the data I have put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st of all, you're selecting from 2 tables but without any link restrictions, so all rows are compared

If there is a matching key between the tables, so only relevant pairs of rows would be compared, it should be used, in a JOIN statement:

```
A e JOIN B t ON e.id = t.id
```

2nd of all, in order to select relevant lines, you should decide what these are.. 
you can inside a WHERE statement define whatvare the relent cases

```
WHERE
e.cAvg > 12
```

You can use the case statement inside WHERE but then the result should be conditioned are returned TRUE

```
SELECT e.Id,e.cAvg, t.Model

 A e JOIN B t ON e.id = t.id

WHERE 
CASE WHEN e.cAvg<=6 THEN t.Model when t.Cr=6 then t.Model
WHEN e.cAvg>6 and e.cAvg<=12 THEN t.Model
WHEN t.Cr='12' then t.Model
WHEN e.cAvg>12 and cg<=24 THEN t.Model
WHEN t.Cr='24' then t.Model
ELSE -1 END ! = -1
```

**EDIT**

Following you question edit, I think that what you need is a `JOIN` with a condition
Basically, instead of joining the tables with an equal key, join them with an unequal key.

Since you're looking for cAvg BETWEEN to t. Cr rows, 2 JOINs are needed

```
SELECT e.Id,e.cAvg, t.Model
   FROM
     A e JOIN B t ON
e.cAvg >= t.Cr
     JOIN B t2 ON
e.cAvg < t2.Cr
WHERE
t.Cr IS NOT NULL
AND t2.Cr IS NOT NULL
```

The idea is that only where the 2 conditions  are met, you would get the results of e
Hope that helps

Comment: @AbhilashGopalakrishna sure. an upvote (and if a good answer a vi mark) would be nice  :)

Comment: Hi thank you for the direction!!!
 I went through joins, I have updated the question as i realized it was too vague.

My problem is as follow:
 - the two tables have no common columns to use JOIN.
 - I want Table B to just compare the values of A and B.
 - Then I need to select the row which satisfies the comparison in Table B.
 - From the same row I want to select a column value from Table B.

JOIN as I understood selects all the rows, but I want to select only the row that satisfies the comparison.

Comment: Totally lost. I have the logic down I guess, but being new to t-sql or any type of query language I have no clue what to use to implement the logic.

Thank you!!

Comment: @AbhilashGopalakrishna Happy to help. Try editing the question, I will edit answer, maybe I can help more :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a possible work around for the problem.

**Problem Statement:**

- Compare two tables with no common column.
- Use the comparison in CASE to select a particular row.
- A WHERE Clause inside CASE is not accepted in T-SQL.

**My Work Around :**

- Add a new column in the second table.
- Assign An id from Table B to the column in Table A.
- Use the assigned id to select the required row in Table B.

Tables:

Table A:

```
+----+------+                           
| id | cAvg |
+----+------+
|  1 | .8   |
|  2 | 5.4  |
|  3 | 6.0  |
+----+------+
```

Table B

```
+-----+-----+-------+
| Bid | Cr  | Model |
+-----+-----+-------+
| 1   | 2   | M1    |
| 2   | 5.5 | M2    |
| 3   | 8   | M3    |
+-----+-----+-------+
```

Query to assign id's:

```
CREATE VIEW [AssignIDView] AS
SELECT DISTINCT e.id,
       e.cAvg,
       (CASE 
            WHEN e.cAvg>=0 and e.cAvg<=2 THEN 1
            WHEN e.cAvg>2 and e.cAvg<=5.5 THEN 2
            WHEN e.cAvg>3 and e.cAvg<=8 THEN 3


        ELSE 'Invalid'
       END) As BId
FROM A e, B t;
```

The result of the above Query will be a view as follows:

```
+----+------+-----+
| id | cAvg | Bid |
+----+------+-----+
|  1 | .8   |   1 |
|  2 | 5.4  |   2 |
|  3 | 6.0  |   3 |
+----+------+-----+
```

Now use Bid to select rows from table B to assign Model from B:

Query:

```
 CREATE VIEW [ModelAssignView] AS
 select e.id,
   e.cAvg,
   t.Model as [Model]
 FROM A e, B t where e.TierID = t.id;
```

The result of the Query will be as follows:

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | cAvg | Model |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | .8   |   M1  |
|  2 | 5.4  |   M2  |
|  3 | 6.0  |   M3  |
+----+------+-------+
```

The intention  of my question was to do the above.
For that I wanted to find an Equivalent of A WHERE Clause inside CASE.

But the above method achieved the solution for me.
Hope it helps:)!